# jQuery hide menu when user clicks anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have a button which opens a menu. When the user selects the button the menu opens and the button is 'pressed' i.e blue colored
when the user makes a selection from the menu the menu closes and the button is unpressed.
if the user selects the button and then instead of choosing an item they click outside of the button, the menu closes and buttonis again unpressed.

my issue is: when i open the menu using the button i should be able to reclick on the button and close it. except when i reclick it opens it again.
i think i need to add something to the press event i have but not sure what. i tried adding `event.stopPropogation()` to the press but it returned not 
a function.

```
    $(document).click(function() {
        this._button.setPressed(false);
    }.bind(this));

    this._button = new ToggleButton({
        press: function(event) {
            if (this._button.getPressed()) {
                menu.open(
                    false,
                    this.getFocusDomRef(),
                    this.getDomRef()
                );
            } else {
                menu.close();
            }
        }.bind(this)
    }).addStyleClass("oButton");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a solution. You would see whether it is good for you.
You can create a layer element after pressed the button. Then, the z-index of the menu is the highest and then the layer element is higher than the background.

You can add a click event to the layer. if the layer is clicked, close the menu.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i dont want to add any elements. do you suggest anything for this?